# Using sails with passport js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I am using sails with passport js for authentication. I have followed the code in the below link for reference.

> http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/77311774912/creating-a-sails-application-using-passport

I am trying to login using the user credentials but it does not work. I have made changes in the middleware according to the the comments and inserted the code in http.js
But the login is not getting authenticated. Please let me know where I am going wrong or what other changes I have to make.

I have uploaded the project on Git Hub. Please check if I am making any fatal errors.

> https://github.com/kchodankar/SailsTest

Comment: have you tried sails-auth? https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth

Comment: I have tried using sails-auth but I am facing problem when I am trying to connect to mySql database. Also the project does not have UI and accepts and returns JSON response

Comment: If the project does not have UI, do you use AJAX from another domain to call your Sails app?

Comment: I am using POSTMAN client to post to my sails web service. I have posted another project using sails auth. But I am getting authentication problem when I connect and fetch from mysql.https://github.com/kchodankar/SailsAuth

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda old but it came up while I was researching a similar issue. Looking at your repo, in https://github.com/kchodankar/SailsTest/blob/master/config/http.js, `passportInit` and `passportSession` need to be in the `order` stack so that passport will get called/initiated when middleware stack is invoked.

```
passportInit: require('passport').initialize(),
passportSession: require('passport').session(),

order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'passportInit', // <===== passportInit
  'passportSession', // <===== passportSession
  'bodyParser',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
]
```